# Can I compile/run/use Citadel CA standalone without Istio?

Tags: istio

Can I compile/run/use Citadel CA standalone without Istio? I tried searching for citadel github but don't find relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

You cant find any about Citadel because there is nothing. I found [deployments](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/citadel_extras/istio-citadel-with-health-check.yaml.tmpl) in istio repositories:
As you see:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: istio-citadel
  namespace: {ISTIO_NAMESPACE}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        istio: citadel
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: istio-citadel-service-account
      containers:
      - name: citadel
        image: {CITADEL_HUB}/citadel:{CITADEL_TAG}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/usr/local/bin/istio_ca"]
        args:
          - --append-dns-names=true
          - --citadel-storage-namespace={ISTIO_NAMESPACE}
          - --grpc-port=8060
          - --grpc-hostname=citadel
          - --self-signed-ca=false
          - --signing-cert=/etc/cacerts/ca-cert.pem
          - --signing-key=/etc/cacerts/ca-key.pem
          - --root-cert=/etc/cacerts/root-cert.pem
          - --cert-chain=/etc/cacerts/cert-chain.pem
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cacerts
          mountPath: /etc/cacerts
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: cacerts
        secret:
          secretName: cacerts
          optional: true
```

so with this you can use it without whole istio in Kubernetes. For using standalone you can try to fetch a [docker image from dockerhub:](https://hub.docker.com/r/istio/citadel/tags/)

```
docker pull istio/citadel:$tag
```

and try to work with it. 
Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/security/cmd/istio_ca is it; if you have a working Go build environment it may or may not work to `go install github.com/istio/istio/security/cmd/istio_ca`.

If you're just looking to run something you also might consider Hashicorp's [Vault](https://vaultproject.io/) which is more directly runnable as a standalone service.  It includes [a module to generate TLS certificates](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/pki/index.html).  (Note that the way it uses them is a little non-traditional: since Vault's expectation is that a service will call Vault whenever it needs a secret, it can generate a new (valid, signed) certificate on every service startup; which means you trade the problem of saving and distributing certificates for the problem of authenticating to Vault.)